# Show Hide List Using Only CSS (No JavaScript)

Tags: css

Please note my code is below.

Here is what I am trying to do.

When the page opens I would like to only have the following 2 expandable items visible:

```
Routing and Switching Classes
Security Classes
```

In other words I would like to have everything collapsed.

When you click on either of the above items I would like to have only that item expand as follows:

Routing and Switching Classes

```
    Certification Classes
    Product Classes
```

or

```
Security Classes

    Certification Classes
    Product Classes
```

When you click on either of the Certification Classes or Product Classes items I would like to have only that item expand as follows:

```
    Certification Classes

        Class Outline 1
        Class Outline 2
        Class Outline 3
```

or

```
    Product Classes

        Class Outline 1
        Class Outline 2
        Class Outline 3
```

Each class outline item would be a link to another page that is the outline for that class.  For demo purposes I have linked to www.weather.com.

Here is what it would look like when everything is expanded:

[Hide Routing and Switching Classes]

```
[Certification Classes] 

    1.Class Outline 1
    2.Class Outline 2
    3.Class outline 3

[Product Training Classes] 

    1.Class Outline 1
    2.Class Outline 2
    3.Class outline 3

[Hide Security Classes] 

    [Certification Classes] 

        1.Class Outline 1
        2.Class Outline 2
        3.Class outline 3

    [Product Training Classes] 

        1.Class Outline 1
        2.Class Outline 2
        3.Class outline 3
```

The problem I am having is that when I open the page everything is expanded by default  instead of just showing the Routing and Switching Classes and Security Classes items.

I want to stay with pure CSS.

Below is my code.  Can you please help me?  It would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

menu mockup

```
<style type="text/css">
    .show {display: none; }
    .hide:focus + .show {display: inline; }
    .hide:focus { display: none; }
    .hide:focus ~ #list { display:none; }
    @media print { .hide, .show { display: none; } }
</style>
```

```
  <div>

    <a href="#" class="hide">[Hide Routing and Switching Classes]</a>
    <a href="#" class="show">[Display Routing and Swithing Classes]</a>

    <ol id="list">

        <div>

            <a href="1" class="hide">[Certification Classes]</a>
            <a href="1" class="show">[Certification Classes]</a>

            <ol id="list">

                <br>

                <li><a href=http://www.weather.com>Class Outline 1</a></li>
                <li>Class Outline 2</li>
                <li>Class outline 3</li>
            </ol>
        </div>

        <div>

            <a href="2" class="hide">[Product Training Classes]</a>
            <a href="2" class="show">[Product Training Classes]</a>

            <ol id="list">

                <br>

                <li><a href=http://www.weather.com>Class Outline 1</a></li>
                <li>Class Outline 2</li>
                <li>Class outline 3</li>

            </ol>
        </div>
     </ol>
  </div>

  <div>

    <a href="3" class="hide">[Hide Security Classes]</a>
    <a href="3" class="show">[Display Security Classes]</a>

    <ol id="list">

        <div>

            <a href="4" class="hide">[Certification Classes]</a>
            <a href="4" class="show">[Certification Classes]</a>

            <ol id="list">

                <br>

                <li><a href=http://www.weather.com>Class Outline 1</a></li>
                <li>Class Outline 2</li>
                <li>Class outline 3</li>

            </ol>
        </div>

        <div>

            <a href="5" class="hide">[Product Training Classes]</a>
            <a href="5" class="show">[Product Training Classes]</a>

            <ol id="list">

                <br>
                <li><a href=http://www.weather.com>Class Outline 1</a></li>
                <li>Class Outline 2</li>
                <li>Class outline 3</li>

            </ol>
        </div>
     </ol>
  </div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Although not quite been able to follow the details in your question I created a demo of how to do `show/hide` buttons to an element (`#list`) in this demo.

So, in the demo you have 2 "buttons"  one for show and one for hide.

By default, the list is hidden. If you want to change this, you just need to remove the `checked` attribute from `#hideResult` and add it to `#showResult`.

If you want to add more levels you do this exactly like this demo - you need 2 `radio-buttons` before each element that you want to `show/hide` it.

```css
input {
  display:none;  
}

#hideRouting:checked ~ #list {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<label for="hideRouting">[Hide Routing and Switching Classes]</label>
<label for="showRouting">[Display Routing and Swithing Classes]</label>
<input type="radio" id="hideRouting" name="routing" checked />
<input type="radio" id="showRouting" name="routing" />

<ol id="list">
  <div>
    <a href="1" class="hide">[Certification Classes]</a>
    <a href="1" class="show">[Certification Classes]</a>
    <ol id="list">
      <li><a href=http://www.weather.com>Class Outline 1</a></li>
      <li>Class Outline 2</li>
      <li>Class outline 3</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="2" class="hide">[Product Training Classes]</a>
    <a href="2" class="show">[Product Training Classes]</a>
    <ol id="list">
      <li><a href=http://www.weather.com>Class Outline 1</a></li>
      <li>Class Outline 2</li>
      <li>Class outline 3</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</ol>
```